# Servlet gives 404 (Eclipse + Tomcat)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm learning with Lars Vogel's tutorial on http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseWTP/article.html and I'm stuck with a 404 error.
So I created a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and then created FileDao.java and FileCounter.java according to the tutorial. And Eclipse generated a web.xml file for me, here it is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>de.vogella.wtp.filecounter</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
  <servlet>
    <description></description>
    <display-name>FileCounter</display-name>
    <servlet-name>FileCounter</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>de.vogella.wtp.filecounter.servlets.FileCounter</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FileCounter</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FileCounter</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I'm using Tomcat 6.0 and I chose Dynamic web module version 2.5 while creating the project.

Comment: How do you access the web application (URL)? Anything in the logs?

Comment: What's the source code of the servlet class? Have you deployed the webapp? What context path did you choose for the webapp? What URL are you typing in the address bar of your browser to invoke the servlet?

Comment: Now I've searched a little more and here is what I found: I changed url-pattern from /FileCounter to *.do and now it works properly! Could you please explain what have I done?

Concerning comments: I access web application through browser, typing http://localhost:8080/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/FileCounter. Besides that, I don't know where to find logs, how to deploy the webapp and what is context path - I just run the app on server through Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

What URL are you trying to access? ... Try

```
http://localhost:8080/<Include Your Project Name>/FileCounter
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing! My project's name is de.vogella.wtp.filecounter, and I'm accessing localhost:8080/de.vogella.wtp.filecounter/FileCounter

Comment: First check if your app has been deployed in Tomcat's WebApps folder.

Comment: I am guessing that the Name of the war is different from the Project Name. Check the name of the folder in Tomcat's webapp folder.